# how to set border bottom equal lenght of wrapped text

Tags: html, css

[Here I attached my work. I want that border full wrap content length width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VABha.jpg)

Comment: Please Read the link  [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What do you want to achieve.. do you want to build similar to that?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question very well. Anyway I just did the design what you've attached. Here is the [link](https://codepen.io/thanooshan/pen/ZNXEvg). I hope this is what you looking for.

**html**

```
<div>
    <div class="inner-content">
        <h2>cda ramadan campaign</h2>
        <p>culturally releavant communication</p><a href="">view work<i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-right"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
  background: #FF5656;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 300px;
}
div h2 {
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
div p {
  color: white;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
div a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
}
div a i {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

**Output**

[image]